# Repeat list elements based in another list

Tags: python, list, repeat

I would like to repeat elements from one list based in a second list, like this:

```py
i = 0
j = [1, 4, 10]
z = [11.65, 11.69, 11.71]
for x in j:
    while i <= x:
        print(x)
        i += 1
```

I've got this result:

```
1
1
4
4
4
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
11.65
11.65
11.69
11.69
11.69
11.71
11.71
11.71
11.71
11.71
11.71
```

Comment: j is 1, 4, 10, and you want to repeat 2, 3 and 6 times, I don't get it ^^

Comment: do you mean anything smaller than 10 prints 11.65 and 10 or more print 11.71?

Comment: Oh, j is an cumulative sum of the occurences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may iterate on both list together, using `zip`, then increase `i` until you reach the bound of the current value

```
i = 0
j = [1, 4, 10]
z = [11.65, 11.69, 11.71]
for bound, value in zip(j, z):
    while i <= bound:
        print(value)
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
j = [1, 4, 10]
z = [11.65, 11.69, 11.71]
for i in range(len(j)): #assuming the lenth of both list is always the same
    for k in range(j[i]):
        print(z[i])
```

Do you mean something like this?

there is a 1, 4, and 10

so print the first item in z 1 time, second item 4 times and the third 10 times?

Comment: The goal is to create a new list, len 10. The size will be the number of the last element of the j list. So, repeating 1 time, I want to the first element of the z list, between 2 and 4 interactions, a want to repeat the second element of the z list, and between 5 and 10 interactions I want to repeat the last element of the z list.
That's a short example. My real lists are a buncha big.